# Rails rspec undefined method `receive_message' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to mock some data inside `before(:each)` and get

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `receive_message' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::CurrencyExchange:0x007f87c652f3c8>
```

my `before(:each`

```
before(:each) do
  @rates = {"exchangerates"=>
            {"row"=>
                 [{"exchangerate"=>{"ccy"=>"EUR", "base_ccy"=>"UAH", "buy"=>"28.33917", "sale"=>"28.33917"}},
                  {"exchangerate"=>{"ccy"=>"RUR", "base_ccy"=>"UAH", "buy"=>"0.38685", "sale"=>"0.38685"}},
                  {"exchangerate"=>{"ccy"=>"USD", "base_ccy"=>"UAH", "buy"=>"24.88293", "sale"=>"24.88293"}},
                  {"exchangerate"=>{"ccy"=>"BTC", "base_ccy"=>"USD", "buy"=>"605.3695", "sale"=>"669.0926"}}]}}
 obj = double()
 @request = allow(obj).to receive_message(@rates)


end
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's just `receive`, unless you are allowing multiple messages, then it's `receive_messages` - plural.

Example:

```
allow(obj).to receive(:method_name)
allow(obj).to receive(:method_1 => :result_1, :method_2 => :result_2)
```

See [the Relish documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/allowing-messages).