# Rails rspec undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-mocha

I want to test that some instance is not receiving a specific method call. Trying to

```
RSpec.describe 'something' do
  before { subject.stubs(foo: 'bar') }
  it { is_expected.to_not receive(:foo) }
end
```

gives me

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to_not receive(:foo) }

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Something:0x0000000010391588>
```

and trying to

```
RSpec.describe 'something else' do
  before { subject.stubs(foo: 42) }
  it { subject.expects(:foo).never; subject.foo }
end
```

passes. What am I doing wrong?

I was directed to the current not-working solution by [Rails rspec undefined method `receive_message' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054147/rails-rspec-undefined-method-receive-message-for-rspecexamplegroups#38054400) and I am using

```
RSpec 3.7
  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-support 3.7.1
```

Update 1: I am using `webmock` instead of `rspec-mocks`.

Update 2: I am using `webmock` and `mocha`.

Update 3: Thanks for all the explanations, @engineersmnky! Unfortunately, for my specific use case, I still need to stub the method. Why is this one still passing?

```
require 'rspec'
require 'mocha'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha
end

RSpec.describe 'something' do
  # passes
  it 'can hide from foo' do 
    subject.stubs(:foo)
    expects(:foo).never
    subject.foo
  end
end
```

The difference is that I tried to express that I expect the signal `:foo` never to be sent.

Comment: we need more here because this works just fine `subject { double }; it { is_expected.not_to receive(:anything) }`

Comment: @engineersmnky the subject is set to the strings of the `describe` blocks: `'something'` and `'something else'`, implicitly. Also, the stubbing isn't the problem / is working. I am bound to `mocker`, I think.

Comment: @Anthony your test is passing as it indeed isn't calling `subject.anything` or `subject.send :anything`. In the MWE my test is calling it directly. In my actual code, I have an explicit subject that may call the method internally, that I don't want it to call. But all of this shouldn't (must not) make a difference.

Comment: @jonas-schulze where in your first example are you calling `subject.foo`?

Comment: @Anthony Nowhere, hence I would expect it to pass.

Comment: if you remove the before block does it pass?  I can't find that stubbing syntax in the rspec docs (closest was this: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/old-syntax/stub)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170106/discussion-between-anthony-and-jonas-schulze).

Comment: No it doesn't pass. I get the same error. RE the stubbing: as said above, I am not using `rspec-mocks` but a different framework: `webmock`.

Comment: @engineersmnky `it { subject.expects(:foo).never; subject.foo; puts subject.class.name }` puts `String` for me. Adding a `subject { 'something' }` to the second example does not change anything for me.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am using `mocha`. Are you able to reproduce my errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so there are 2 problems here. First is you are trying to use rspec expectations syntax with `mocha` as your mocking frame work. This causes the:

```
undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Something:0x0000000010391588>
```

Error because `mocha` does not know about `receive`. The syntax for `mocha` should be:

```
it { expects(:foo).never }
```

Your next issue is the before block is stubbing `foo` so it never actually reaches the receiver. So your second case passes because `subject` never actually receives `foo` because the stubbing intercepts the call.

Example:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'mocha'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha
end

def stub_obj(obj,method_list)
  Class.new(SimpleDelegator) do 
      method_list.each do |k,v| 
          define_method(k) {v}
      end
  end.new(obj)
end

RSpec.describe 'something' do

  subject {mock('subject')}
  #passes 
  it { expects(:foo).never }
  # fails 
  it { subject.expects(:foo).never; subject.foo }
  # passes 
  it 'can hide from foo' do 
    subject.stubs(:foo)
    subject.expects(:foo).never
    subject.foo
  end

  context 'kind of like this' do
    # passes
    it 'hides with a stubbed method' do
      stubber = stub_obj(subject, foo: 'bar')
      subject.expects(:foo).never
      stubber.foo
    end
    # fails 
    it 'cannot hide from a non-stubbed method' do
      stubber = stub_obj(subject, foo: 'bar')
      subject.expects(:bar).never
      stubber.bar
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the implementation of [`Object#stubs`](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/ObjectMethods.html#stubs-instance_method) if you are interested and while it does a bit more than my example (`#stub_obj`) through a `Mocha::Mockery` object the concept is the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately my problem still isn't solved. I updated my question (update 3). I would be pleased if you could take a look, again.

Comment: @jonas-schulze as I described the stub intercepts the call to the receiver so `subject` never actually receives `foo` (thus the test passes) if you must test that functionality you should do so in isolation away from the stubbed `foo`

Comment: @jonas-schulze I have added an example that is as clean as I can possibly represent this "hiding" feature