# undefined method `receive' in Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-mocha

I am trying to test a `worker` in `Rspec` using `receive`. (This test in for my `user.rb` model)

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'cancan/matchers'

describe User, type: :model do

  context 'when an user' do
    subject(:ability) { Ability.new(user) }
    let(:user) { create(:user, :user) }

    it 'does not have admin role' do
      expect(user.is_admin?).to be_falsey
    end

    it { is_expected.to be_able_to(:destroy, user) }

    it 'has a profile when created' do
      target = create(:user)
      expect(target.profile).to be_present
    end

    it 'calls a worker when user is created' do
      expect(CreateContactWorker).to receive(:perform_async).once(user_id, first_name, last_name, email)
    end
  end
end
```

This is where my worker is being called in my `user.rb` model:

```
def create_contact
    CreateContactWorker.perform_async(id, first_name, last_name, email)
end
```

Now, when testing this I get an error:

```
Failures:

  1) User calls a worker when user is created
     Failure/Error: expect(CreateContactWorker).to receive(:perform_async).once(user_id, first_name, last_name, email)
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::User "calls a worker when user is created" (./spec/models/user_spec.rb:43)>
```

Now, doing some research looks like `receive` is a `mocha` syntax? But what exactly is the difference between one and the `rspec` syntax?
And of course, what am I doing wrong?  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails rspec undefined method `receive' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50105319/2788206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow the worker to receive calls, use the following.

```
it 'calls a worker when user is created' do
  allow(CreateContactWorker).to receive(:perform_async)
  subject
  expect(CreateContactWorker).to have_received(:perform_async).with(user_id, first_name, last_name, email).once
end
```